# How to check if a coordinate are between 2 sets of coordinates (Google Maps - Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For example I have:

- start (51.533407, -0.203948)
- point (51.531966, -0.210987)
- end (51.530951, -0.216823)
- origin (51.533487, -0.187812)
- destination (51.529189, -0.220814)

So, how can I know that "point" is between "start" and "end" and not between "origin" and "start" or "end" and "destination?

I already tried:

- minimum distance between coordinates - is not a solution, because can give wrong results;
- comparing street name (feature name, thoroughfare, subthoroughfare - Address) with the "html_instruction" from Directions API - is not working everytime and sometimes the street name is null;
- comparing street name (feature name, thoroughfare, subthoroughfare - Address) with "long_name" ("address_components") from Geocode API -> useless, because i can't get coordinates from "start" and "end" and sometimes the street name is null (eg: on villages).

Any other ideas? I already searched on the internet but i couldn't find something that I need.

Thank you,
Maxim

Image Link: [google map](http://s14.postimg.org/yshk16mi9/map_android.png)

Comment: I want to see a picture of what your asking.  I think you could answer the question if you could draw a picture of what your asking.

Comment: I couldn't post the image, because i don't have 10 points of reputation, so i post the link http://s14.postimg.org/yshk16mi9/map_android.png

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line. You could calc the distance between point and line between start and end, the distance between point and line between start an origin, distance between point and line between end and destination.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an analytically solution, its upto you how you can implement with the code (I would recommend using Geofencing API provided in Android's Google Play Services library).

- Consider the "point" to be the center of circle.
- Find the close point, For Example "Start".
- Consider that distance as radius and draw a circle.
- You may now know all the coodinates (points) inside the circle.
- Find distances from the center to all the points included in the Geofence (Circle).
- Subtract each with the "point's" distance.
- The minimum distance obtained after subtraction would be the point opposite to the "point".
- Hence you can know that in between which two coodinates your "point" lies.

If there are no coordintes in the geofence in the radius drawn between "point" & "start" then increase the radius till the time you dont find the first coordinate. This will be another point besides "point" & "Start".

Hope this would Help!!!